# Question about a step in the proof of ratio test limit implies root test has same limit

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

> Let $(a_n)_n$ be a positive sequence such that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \to a$ when $n\to\infty$; then $\sqrt[n]{a_n} \to a$ when $n\to\infty$.

My lecturer proved this theorem test using, at some point, the fact that for any $n \ge N$ it is $a-\epsilon<\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<a+\epsilon$, so this holds in particular for $N+1,N+2,...,N+n$ and hence $(a-\epsilon)^n a_N<a_{N+n}<(a+\epsilon)^na_N$.

However, I tried to build these steps (the lecturer didn't prove this, he left it as an exercise) and got stuck at one point. From the limit hypothesis on the ratio it follows
$$(a-\epsilon)a_N<a_{N+1}<(a+\epsilon)a_N$$

$$(a-\epsilon) a_{N+1}<a_{N+2}<(a+\epsilon) a_{N+1}$$
$$\vdots$$
$$(a-\epsilon) a_{N+n-1}<a_{N+n}<(a+\epsilon) a_{N+n-1}$$
But, to increase the powers of $a-\epsilon$ and $a+\epsilon$ in the inequality of $a_{N+2}$, I must multiply the inequality $a_{N+1}<(a+\epsilon) a_N$ for $a+\epsilon$ and the inequality $(a-\epsilon)a_N < a_{N+1}$ for $a-\epsilon$ and proceed $n$ times like this to arrive at the inequality I need for $a_{N+n}$.

While it is clear to me that $a+\epsilon>0$ because $\epsilon>0$ and, since by hypothesis $a_n>0$, the limit $a$ of $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ is $a \ge 0$, it is not completely clear to me (if not an intuitive way that I express later in this question) that $a-\epsilon>0$ as well and so I am not sure to multiply for a nonnegative number in the inequalities to preserve the order. I tried induction too, but I still have the same doubts about the sign of $a-\epsilon$.

I see intuitively that we are interested in "small $\epsilon$" and so I think I can assume $\epsilon$ small enough to be sure that $a-\epsilon>0$, however this means that $0<\epsilon<a$ and the definition of limit requires "for any $\epsilon>0$, not only "for $0<\epsilon<a$". I seen sometimes that assuming, for example, $0<\epsilon<1$ doesn't make the proof lose generality, so I think that this is a situation similar to those when it is assumed $0<\epsilon<1$, but I don't see how it is possible to deduce that this holds for general case "for any $\epsilon>0$" from the fact that it holds in the particular case "$0<\epsilon<a$".

Can someone explain me what is happening in this particular theorem and prove me that, in general, doing assumption on $\epsilon$ doesn't make any proof about limits less general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, restricting to small $\epsilon>0$ is wlog. For example:

> > Suppose that for every $\epsilon\in(0,1)$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. Then the same holds for every $\epsilon>0$.

Proof. Suppose $\epsilon\ge1$. Choose $\delta>0$ so that $|x-y|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|<1/2$. Then $|x-y|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|<1/2<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

If $a=0$ then $\frac {a_{n+1}} {a_n} \to 0$. In this case above argument gives $a_n^{1/n} \leq \epsilon$ for $n$ sufficiently large. This implies that $a_n^{1/n} \to 0$. There is no need for an inequality on the other side in this case.

Your lecturer's proof becomes valid for $a=0$ if you replace $a-\epsilon$ in the proof by $\max \{a-\epsilon, 0\}$.